# Automatically detect and embed MP4/MP3 Links in html content using PHP

Tags: php, regex, video, html5-audio

I am writing a simple blog for my website and I have succeeded in doing this.

```
function convertYoutube($string, $id='') {
        return preg_replace(
            "/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i",
            "<div class=videoWrapper><iframe style=\"clear:both;\" width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$2\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            ",
            $string
        );
    }
```

That is converting a youtube url(short or long) to an embed form.

Now what I wish to do is this:

- convert mp4 links, eg: 
  `http://cdn.example.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4?id=28gsbd0mu&d=33hfsbb`
   into

  `<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>`
- convert mp3 links into equivalent  tag format

However, I don't want to convert links such as this

```
<a href="http://cdn.example.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4">DOWNLOAD VIDEO</a>
```

I want them to stay intact like that, for both mp4 and mp3 links.

**EDITED**

What I want is this:

```html
This is a very nice Video by Artiste So-n-So    https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13229628_1095069080586346_1424116369_n.mp4

<a href="http://cdn.example.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4?id=28gsbd0mu&d=33hfsbb">
Download Video</a>
```

[image]

```html
This is a very nice Video by Artiste So-n-So     <video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13229628_1095069080586346_1424116369_n.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<a href="http://cdn.example.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4?id=28gsbd0mu&d=33hfsbb">
Download Video</a>
```

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: how would you go from *<source src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13229628_1095069080586346_1424116369_n.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>* to *<a href="http://cdn.example.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4?id=28gsbd0mu&d=33hfsbb">
Download Video</a>*?

Comment: there's no apparent mapping or relation between the cdinstagram video and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will find the mp4 URLs:

```
(["\']?https?:\/\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*?.mp4\?(&?\w+(=[^&\'"\s]*)?)*)
```

After that there's some PHP code to replace the URL with the video and source tags.  Note that this now captures leading quote characters to determine if the URL is contained in a `href=""` or `src=""` link; the code below explicitly checks for that and skips URLs found that start with quote characters.  See the second URL in the first example to see how that works.

Here is the sample code using the URL to parse standalone MP4 URLs from text:

```
$subject = <<<LABEL
    This is a very nice Video by Artiste So-n-So    https://s...content-available-to-author-only...m.com/t50.2886-16/13229628_1095069080586346_1424116369_n.mp4


        <a href="http://c...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4?id=28gsbd0mu&d=33hfsbb">
        Download Video</a>"
LABEL;

$subject = <<<LABEL
Please one more thing, can you expand your regex to include URLs like these.
https://z-1-scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-4/13226507_264732453878764_‌​308543824_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&oh=c68eadae7d9a5b25ad290ea72‌​3f8fc40&oe=57378FA2 
that is URLs that doesn't end immediately with the extension, but have other parameters added to it.
LABEL;

$pattern = '(["\']?https?:\/\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*?.mp4\?(&?\w+(=[^&\'"\s]*)?)*)';
$matches = Array();
$match = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

if (count($matches) !== 0) {
    $first_char = substr($matches[0], 0, 1);
    if ($first_cahr !== '"' && $first_char !== "'") {
        $replace = '<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="' . $matches[0] . '" type="video/mp4"></video>';

        $result = str_replace($matches[0], $replace, $subject);

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

The output for the first test case is:

```
Success time: 0.03 memory: 52480 signal:0
    This is a very nice Video by Artiste So-n-So    <video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/13229628_1095069080586346_1424116369_n.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>


        <a href="http://cdn.example.com/akndh39/2016/askbdsjdbuu/my-video.mp4?id=28gsbd0mu&d=33hfsbb">
        Download Video</a>"
```

The output for the second test case is:

```
Please one more thing, can you expand your regex to include URLs like these.
<video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="https://z-1-scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-4/13226507_264732453878764_‌​308543824_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&oh=c68eadae7d9a5b25ad290ea72‌​3f8fc40&oe=57378FA2" type="video/mp4"></video> 
that is URLs that doesn't end immediately with the extension, but have other parameters added to it.
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it out and comment back.

Comment: What does that mean?  It worked on the sample input, so if it's failing with other input that's different, can you let me know what it is so that I can fix it?  I'm the only one that's even attempted to give you an answer so far, so please help me to help you.

Comment: Ok I found the issue, I using that function with an embed library https://www.warpconduit.net/2013/04/13/automatically-embedding-video-using-only-the-url-with-the-help-of-oembed/

I found that the library return blank any url that cannot be embedded.

So i believe that is the issue here, however i removed the library from my code and yours worked well enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Please one more thing, can you expand your regex to include URLs like these.
`https://z-1-scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-4/13226507_264732453878764_308543824_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&oh=c68eadae7d9a5b25ad290ea723f8fc40&oe=57378FA2`

that is URLs that doesn't end immediately with the extension, but have other parameters added to it.

Comment: I updated the regex and the test code, so you should be able to see what changes I made and how it works.

Comment: This one doesn't really work well, can't pin point the error as laravel is throwing unreadable errors for me.

But thanks, I go with the first one.

Comment: If you have more sample URLs, I could figure out which, if any, are not working.  I don't know laravel at all, so I'd be no help there.  But one question: did you take into account that the query now includes a leading quote?  I included the description of that at the top of the answer, and showed how to deal with it in the example code.